# Is there a Firestore Timestamp in metadata for Document Creation?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp, metadata

I am wondering if Cloud Firestore timestamps each document on creation in its metadata, and if so, is that metadata available?

I know I can create my own timestamps inside a document for arbitrary reasons, but I'm only interested in when the document itself was created.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that if you really don't want to add a Timestamp field when you create the doc from your front end, as explained by Alex, you could use a [Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) to do so (`onCreate` event).

Comment: Thanks Renaud. 
Its not that I'm adverse to trigger functions. Its just that I'm trying to establish the exact time the document is written to establish ordering. Putting it in a cloud function would not provide me with this (i.e. with a trigger function it would be after the fact and possible retries mean that it could be way inaccurate)

Comment: I do understand your requirement! I was just mentioning another possibility :-)

Comment: Ahh, no worries Renaud. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit Apr 27'th 2023:**

In [google.firestore.v1](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rpc/google.firestore.v1) the [document](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rpc/google.firestore.v1#document) contains now `create_time` and `update_time`, both being of type [Timestamp](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/google.protobuf#google.protobuf.Timestamp).

---

**Edit Jan 21'th 2022:**

In Android, you can call [DocumentSnapshot.getMetadata()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getMetadata()) method or [QuerySnapshot.getMetadata()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot#getMetadata()), which both return an object of type [SnapshotMetadata](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/SnapshotMetadata). By the time I'm editing this answer, in this class there is **no** method that returns a timestamp. There is only a [hasPendingWrites()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/SnapshotMetadata#hasPendingWrites()) and [isFromCache()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/SnapshotMetadata#isFromCache()).

---

> I am wondering if Firestore timestamps each document on creation in its metadata

No, it does not.

> I know I can create my own timestamps inside a document

That's the solution you should go ahead with. Add the timestamp of the creation as a field within every document.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Do you knw if this server timestamp() generated by client or the server(database)?

Comment: The server timestamp is generated on Firebase servers. Only the documents ids are generated on the client.

Answer (score 15):

The accepted answer is actually not true for the latest beta release of firestore, you can access the creation date from the meta data e.g. in python like this:

```py
doc.create_time
```

in JavaScript you can get the date like this:

```js
const creationDate = new Date(doc.createTime._seconds * 1000)
```

Just have a look at the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rpc/google.firestore.v1beta1

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Firebase Firestore provides `create_time` and `update_time` timestamps in v1 if you only need output.
https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rpc/google.firestore.v1#document

Comment: This would be great to use but I can't seem to get a query working in Angular Firestore.

Comment: @Tawm - In the Node version, it's doc.createTime

Comment: @Tawm I don't believe you can query by metadata...you can only access it.