# I need to access firebase storage files metadata from a particular folder in the bucket in C# unity

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, cloud

I am unable to find a method to parse through all the files in a firebase storage folder from C# script in Unity and get their metadata to find the latest created file using CreationTimeMillis. Is there any way that is possible.

This is what I tried but the ListAll() method is apparently only available for the web calls and not Unity:

```
private async void FindLatestFileStartingWithA(string extension)
{
    StorageReference folderRef = storageReference.Child("csv_folder");
    List<string> fileList = new List<string>();

    try
    {
        var listResult = await folderRef.ListAll();

        foreach (StorageReference fileRef in listResult.Items)
        {
            string fileName = fileRef.Name;
            if (fileName.StartsWith("A") && fileName.EndsWith(extension))
            {
                fileList.Add(fileName);
            }
        }

        if (fileList.Any())
        {
            string latestFile = fileList[fileList.Count - 1]; // Get the last (latest) file
            Debug.Log("Latest file starting with 'A': " + latestFile);
            file_name = latestFile;

            // Now that we have the latest file name, start the download process
            StartCoroutine(DownloadCSV(file_name));
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("No file found starting with 'A'.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Debug.LogError("Error listing files: " + e.Message);
    }
}
```

This is how the metadata for any csv file looks like on the firebase console, from which I need to access the creation time to get the latest file created:

[image of metadata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwtW2.png)

Comment: Post sample of the meta data files.  We need to see the data to determine how to parse.

Comment: @jdweng
I have added the image to the question, please have a look, thanks

Comment: Looks like latest version you can get timestamp : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59784116/is-there-a-firestore-timestamp-in-metadata-for-document-creation